# Scroll between 2 webview

Tags: android, webview, android-studio

I have 2 webview on the same page and i would like to scroll between these 2. There is my code

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.CUPCAKE)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    WebView webView2 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView2);

    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    webView2.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView2.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);


    webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
    webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
    webView2.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
    webView2.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);

    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView2.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/BarChart.html");
    webView2.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/PieChart.html");
```

I can already zoom on each one of them but i'm still unable to scroll

Thank You

Fab9193.

Comment: Hi everybody by the way !

Comment: what do you mean by "scroll between these 2" ? that if you've scrolled one to the bottom, now the second one would scroll? or maybe scroll them both at the same time?

Comment: I meant both at the same time my bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think making both webviews scroll at the same time by the end user is quite problematic.

the reason is that each webview has its own rules of how to behave according to scrolling - it's a part of the HTML & Javascript mechanism.

you could make the touch events occur on both, but i think it's a bad solution.

if you can, i suggest merging the two webviews into one, and research how to achieve it via javascript.

Comment: i will try but i really don't see how can i do that I’m quite a beginner in android development. Thanks for the issue

Comment: maybe i should make a menu on top and choose between these two charts

Comment: maybe. i think having 2 webviews can be confusing (for the end user) anyway (depends on the app of course) ....

Comment: the thing is its just one part of the app. The goal of the app is kind of a "Proof of Concept" i show what i can do with some api

Comment: you want to show what you can do? you can look at other websites and apps to get inspiration. example : androidviews.net website , devAppsDirect app .